# android add tables to existing database in asset folder dynamically

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an exisiting database which i have made in sqlite db browser containing four tables and placed it in assets folder. Now i want to add more tables dynamically through code into this database. How can this be achieved.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, add the code of what you've already tried. As is, your question is very vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create database by creating the following :

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table mutable (_id integer primary key autoincrement, field1 text not null, field2 text not null);";

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        // Method that creates database
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
                database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }
}
```

Thank you need to create a DBAdabter Class that manipulates data inside that database:

```
public class DbAdapter {
  private Context context;
  private SQLiteDatabase database;
  private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

  // Database fields
  private static final String DATABASE_TABLE      = "mutable";

  public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
  public static final String KEY_FIELD1 = "field1";
  public static final String KEY_FIELD2 = "field2";

  public DbAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  public DbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
  }

  public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
  }

//Create data to be inserted in db
  private ContentValues createContentValues(String field1, String field2) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put( KEY_FIELD1, field1 );
    values.put( KEY_FIELD2, field2 );
   return values;
  }

  //Insert in DB
  public long Insert(String field1, String field2) {
    ContentValues values = createContentValues(field1, field2);
    return database.insertOrThrow(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
  }

//OTHER METHODS FOR RETRIEVING DATA ETC
}
```